# Avoiding page refresh when a form is used in Django

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax, django-views

I have a very basic Django view:

```
 def myview(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if 'button1' in request.POST:
                form1 = form = myForm(request.POST)
                # check whether it's valid:
                if form.is_valid():
                    profile = form.save()
                    profile.user = request.user
                    profile.save()
                    messages.success(request, f"Success")
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
        else:
            form = myForm()

        return render(request,
                      "main/mytemplate.html",
                      context={"form":form})
```

And its template:

```
<form method="post" novalidate>
{% csrf_token %}
{% include 'main/includes/bs4_form.html' with form=form %}
<button name="button1" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Everything works here, when this form is used, some data is saved on my DB. What i would like to change, though, is the page reload after the form is used.

When the Submit button is hit, the page will be refreshed. Since it makes the navigation way slower, i would like to have the view not refreshing the page each time the form is used.

Is it possible to accomplish this in Django? For example, instead of refreshing the page, i would like to only load part of it, or to have a 'Reload' icon while the view is doing its work.

I'm pretty new to Ajax, so i don't know how to get started on this.

Comment: You need to look into AJAX. You already have it as a tag; what have you tried to implement from your reading around this topic? It has nothing (really) to do with Django; provided the web framework can provide a rendered template, all of the work is on the front-end

Comment: Yes, i know Ajax. The problem with this is that there is very little online covering this particular topic

Comment: "Django ajax" in Google --> 6 million results.

Comment: I think it's a bit trickier than this. Using Ajax to add more interactivity to my page is a thing; using it for this task is another level, since the problem is not related to Ajax itself but to Django as well. I don't even know if this is possible, this is why i'm making this question

Comment: It isn't trickier, you're just getting a bit buried (I've been there). All Django has to do is catch the request and render a template back. The payload of the request might be a form or JSON or other. But Django is not responsible for updating a `<div>`, for example. That's for JQuery. I mostly work with Flask so I can't give you an idiomatic answer for Django specifically (since it has a different template language) but [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html) looks decent as a walk-through

Comment: Ok, i'll see what can i do. Thank you!